# How can I narrow a discriminated union, when not all discriminator values are known?

Tags: typescript, types

Consider the case where a library returns an error, and all errors have a `name: string;` field.

I know that a `KnownError` will have `name: 'KnownError'`, and an additional `KnownErrorSpecific: string` field - but I do not know the names of all possible errors.

This sounds like the perfect case for a discriminated union - but since all names are strings, trying to type-narrow on the discriminator doesn't rule out the generic case.

```
type UnknownError = {
    name: string;
};

type KnownErrorOne = {
    name: 'KnownError';
    knownErrorSpecific: string;
};

type KnownErrorTwo = {
    name: 'WarpDriveError';
    warpCoreTemperature: number;
};

type GeneralError = KnownErrorOne | KnownErrorTwo | UnknownError;

const handleError = (err: GeneralError) => {
    if(err.name === 'KnownError' as const){
        console.log(err.knownErrorSpecific);
        // err could be KnownErrorOne or UnknownError
    }
};
```

I believe the correct solution is to type `UnknownError.name` as any string *except* the list of known names. Hypothetically `Omit<string, "KnownError" | "WarpDriveError">`.

Is such a thing possible?

As a workaround, I can use `if( 'knownErrorSpecific' in err )`, but I would like to understand the solution to the above in case I run into this again.

[TS Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgazgewO5wKICcvK1AXigG8AoKCqOAQwFsIAuKAZ2CwEs4BzAblIF8+pUJCgBpFOmy4sAeTjQiZSlTqMoAcglpMOPBr4qkO6XgDKkAMbsAZu0tNWHbn0Glh4aNql6sAFVRkQhJyShp6Jg0AdWosMAARDgA3CFMsA1CKVFiwAGE8CD8IWkgsamAAVyx1OAraACMILFchEWgAcQgFMoAbNODvXRl5aAAfcUkhvACg8fhjHxkhS2Q4VigAC2o4ABMe1N9ggAomrCZO7uo+3wBKQgA+EJVbE5wAOnDFAiItSbSNKDUZhQFZrYA3ZQqSig5jIfZvHrILivLBvBZTLAWCDWOyWG6GKEUAD0RKgpxByAqPR2UEaExMvhGUDwsEQf18mSg-AEPCAA)

Comment: Remove `UnknownError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each type needs to be sound on its own.

So it's totally reasonable for someone to do this:

```
const error: UnknownError = { name: 'KnownError' }
```

And if you pass that object to this function:

```
const handleError = (err: GeneralError) => {
    if(err.name === 'KnownError'){
        console.log(err.knownErrorSpecific); // undefined
    }
};
```

Then you have a problem because that property doesn't exist on that object.

So `name` here is not a sufficient discriminant in this discriminated union. Discriminants need to be mutually exclusive, but `'KnownError'` extends `string`, so they have overlap.

---

Typescript does not have *negative* types. You cannot say what a type is *not*. Which means that you cannot exclude finite values from an infinite set. So you cannot express "any string, except this string" as a type. Same for "any number, except 0".

Which means that if your discriminant overlaps with other members, then you will need to do additional narrowing in order to get it down the type you need.

---

#### Potential solution.

It may be very unlikely that someone will use a known error code for an unknown error. (This is up to you to make that judgement call). So if you decide that's safe enough for your codebase, you can restructure your types a bit and add a typeguard to make this a bit nicer.

First, separate your known errors from the unknown ones in their own union:

```
type UnknownError = {
    name: string;
};

type KnownErrorOne = {
    name: 'KnownError';
    knownErrorSpecific: string;
};

type KnownErrorTwo = {
    name: 'WarpDriveError';
    warpCoreTemperature: number;
};

type KnownError = KnownErrorOne | KnownErrorTwo
type GeneralError = KnownError | UnknownError;
```

Now can keep the `name: string` from polluting the union.

Then we just need a type guard that can accept a `GeneralError`, but validate that object as a KnownError.

```
function isKnownError<
  T extends KnownError['name']
>(
  error: GeneralError,
  name: T
): error is Extract<KnownError, { name: T }> {
  return error.name === name
}
```

This function accepts a `GeneralError` and a name of a `KnownError`. If the name matches it asserts that the the error was of that known type by `Extract`ing all members of the `KnownError` union that match that name.

Now this will work fine:

```
const handleError = (error: GeneralError) => {
    if(isKnownError(error, 'KnownError')){
        console.log(error.knownErrorSpecific); // fine
    }
};
```

Note that there is nothing stopping you from doing this, still:

```
const error: UnknownError = { name: 'KnownError' }
```

Which will likely cause problems at runtime, but it's up to you whether that risk is worth it for this case.

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#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)